# Add an extra column after grep content

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I understand that grep can extract the specific content from a file line by line. 
Just wondering how can add another column before or after each line as an index. 
For example:

```
grep "aaa"  text.txt > tmp.txt
```

In the tmp.txt file, we can see the content as follows,

```
aaawekjre
qejrteraaa
wrgeaaaere
```

However, I would like to add a specific index as an extra column. 
Therefore, the tmp.txt might look like this:

```
John aaawekjre
John qejrteraaa
John wrgeaaaere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   grep "aaa"  text.txt | awk '{print "John " $0}' > tmp.txt
```

Comment: grep | awk seems a bit unnecessary. You can do `awk '/pattern/ {print ...}'` like anubhava does.

Comment: I agree with u, anubhava and john1024 solutions are better than this;

Answer (score 7):

You can use awk:

```
awk '/aaa/{print "John", $0}' text.txt > tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sed -n '/aaa/ s/^/John /p' text.txt
John aaawekjre
John qejrteraaa
John wrgeaaaere
```

#### How it works

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/aaa/ s/^/John /p`

  This selects lines that contain `aaa`.  For those lines, we do a substitution (`s/^/John /`) to put `John` at the beginning of the line and we print the line (`p`).

  In this way, lines that do not contain `aaa` are never printed.  Thus, there is no need for a separate `grep` process.